# Why does my automatic transmission not shift sometimes?

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting

My 2003 Grand Prix sometimes goes into gear and sometimes it won't. Today I'm driving and once my car gets to 40 km/h, it should click into second but it just revs, then it just clicks in. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We could use a little more information to better answer you. Have you checked the transmission fluid level (could just be low)? How many miles are on the car? When was the last time the transmission was serviced? Use the [edit] feature to add these details and we will try to give you as detailed answer as we can.

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level as described in your manual? It could just be low.

Answer (score 2):

Change the transmission fluid.  Then, after a week of driving, change it again.  After another month of driving, change the fluid a third time.

Comment: If that does not help, some transmissions have internal filters - get it replaced.

Comment: Yep. This transmission does have a [changeable filter](http://www.partsgeek.com/catalog/2003/pontiac/grand_prix/transmission/automatic_transmission_filter.html). Less than $20 USD at most national chains. If going to change the fluid, it is worth changing the filter.